# List All Files In A Folder

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I need to list all the files(includes .doc, .pdf,.txt etc) in a folder and able to download and delete that file using jquery/asp.net c#.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is supported on ASP.Net, but `Directory.GetFiles` should work fine to get all the files in a directory. If you need to add support for files inside subdirectories, you can make the method recursive.

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(pathname, "*.sql", 
SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

TopDirectoryOnly does not include subdirectory.

```
for (int i=0; i<filePaths.Length; ++i)
     listtBox1.Items.Add(filePaths[i]);
```

And from this listbox, you can either delete or move your files to another folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
 string filephysicalpath=""; //Specify Physical path of file
 string filevirtualpath =""; //Specify Virtual path of file

 DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(filephysicalpath);
 FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*" + filematch + "*.pdf");

 string strFilename="";
 foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
 {
    strFilename=filevirtualpath + "/" file.Name; // This will give you the full hosted     path of file with name loopwise.. so that you can download it directly by clicking the link.               
 }


//For Deleting file using Jquery my suggestion is write delete code in web service or in another code page and call it using Ajax
```

Answer (score 0):

[Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
```